# VBA/Macro for multiple condition

Tags: excel, vba, random, conditional-statements

I need help to be able to get random data from another workbook with specific conditions:

here is how my data looks like in `rawdata.xlsx`

[image]

If i click a button/run a macro, I should get **4 random samples** `for all rows that has "AU"`, **1 random sample** `for all rows that has "FJ"`, **1 random sample** `for all rows that has "NC"`, **3 random samples** `for all rows that has "NZ"`, and **1 random sample** `for all rows that has "SG12"` ...

... FROM `rawdata.xlsx "Sheet1"` sheet and paste it to `tool.xlsm "Random Sample"` sheet.

All should happen in one click.

This is my code so far:

```
        Option Explicit

Sub MAIN()
Dim key As String
Dim nKeyCells As Long, nRndRows As Long, rOffset As Long
Dim nRowsArr As Variant, keyArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim dataRng As Range, helperRng1 As Range, helperRng2 As Range
Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet

Set rawDataWs = Workbooks("rawdata.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set randomSampleWs = Workbooks("tool.xlsm").Worksheets("Random Sample")

keyArr = Array("AU", "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12") '<== set your keywords
nRowsArr = Array(4, 1, 1, 3, 1) '<== set the n° of random rows to be associated to its correspondant keyword

With rawDataWs
    Set dataRng = .Range("B2:" & .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address) '<== adapt it to your needs. keywords are assumed to be in the firts column of this range
    Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, dataRng)
End With

Set helperRng1 = dataRng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, dataRng.Columns.Count + 1) '<== here will be placed "1"s to mark rows to be copied and pasted: they'll be cleared at the end
For i = 0 To UBound(keyArr)
    nRndRows = CInt(nRowsArr(i))
    key = CStr(keyArr(i))
    nKeyCells = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRng.Resize(, 1), key)
    Set helperRng2 = helperRng1.Offset(, 1).Resize(nRndRows) '<== here will be pasted random numbers: they'll be cleared at the end
    Call Unique_Numbers(1, nKeyCells, nRndRows, helperRng2)
    With helperRng1
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(RC" & dataRng.Columns(2).Column & "=""" & key & """,countif(" & helperRng2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",countif(R" & dataRng.Rows(1).Row & "C" & dataRng.Columns(2).Column & ":RC" & dataRng.Columns(2).Column & ",""" & key & """))>0),1,"""")"
        .value = .value
        Intersect(.EntireRow, dataRng).Copy Destination:=randomSampleWs.Range("A2").Offset(rOffset)
        rOffset = rOffset + nRndRows
        .EntireColumn.Resize(, 2).Clear
    End With
Next i

End Sub


Sub Unique_Numbers(Mn As Long, Mx As Long, Sample As Long, refRange As Range)
Dim tempnum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim foundCell As Range
' adapted from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213290

If Sample > Mx - Mn + 1 Then
    MsgBox "You specified more numbers to return than are possible in the range!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set refRange = refRange.Resize(Sample, 1)

Randomize
refRange(1) = Int((Mx - Mn + 1) * rnd + Mn)
For i = 2 To Sample
    Set foundCell = Nothing
    Do
       Randomize
       tempnum = Int((Mx - Mn + 1) * rnd + Mn)
       Set foundCell = refRange.Find(tempnum)
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing
    refRange(i) = tempnum
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub MAIN()
Dim key As String
Dim nKeyCells As Long, nRndRows As Long, rOffset As Long
Dim nRowsArr As Variant, keyArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim dataRng As Range, helperRng1 As Range, helperRng2 As Range
Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet

Set rawDataWs = Workbooks("rawdata.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set randomSampleWs = Workbooks("tool.xlsm").Worksheets("Random Sample")

keyArr = Array("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD") '<== set your keywords
nRowsArr = Array(4, 1, 3, 1) '<== set the n° of random rows to be associated to its correspondant keyword

With rawDataWs
    Set dataRng = .Range("A2:E200") '<== adapt it to your needs. keywords are assumed to be in the firts column of this range
    Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, dataRng)
End With

Set helperRng1 = dataRng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, dataRng.Columns.Count + 1) '<== here will be placed "1"s to mark rows to be copied and pasted: they'll be cleared at the end
For i = 0 To UBound(keyArr)
    nRndRows = CInt(nRowsArr(i))
    key = CStr(keyArr(i))
    nKeyCells = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRng.Resize(, 1), key)
    Set helperRng2 = helperRng1.Offset(, 1).Resize(nRndRows) '<== here will be pasted random numbers: they'll be cleared at the end
    Call Unique_Numbers(1, nKeyCells, nRndRows, helperRng2)
    With helperRng1
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(RC" & dataRng.Columns(1).Column & "=""" & key & """,countif(" & helperRng2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",countif(R" & dataRng.Rows(1).Row & "C" & dataRng.Columns(1).Column & ":RC" & dataRng.Columns(1).Column & ",""" & key & """))>0),1,"""")"
        .Value = .Value
        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, dataRng).Copy Destination:=randomSampleWs.Range("A2").Offset(rOffset)
        rOffset = rOffset + nRndRows
        .EntireColumn.Resize(, 2).Clear
    End With
Next i

End Sub


Sub Unique_Numbers(Mn As Long, Mx As Long, Sample As Long, refRange As Range)
Dim tempnum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim foundCell As Range
' adapted from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213290

If Sample > Mx - Mn + 1 Then
    MsgBox "You specified more numbers to return than are possible in the range!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set refRange = refRange.Resize(Sample, 1)

Randomize
refRange(1) = Int((Mx - Mn + 1) * Rnd + Mn)
For i = 2 To Sample
    Set foundCell = Nothing
    Do
       Randomize
       tempnum = Int((Mx - Mn + 1) * Rnd + Mn)
       Set foundCell = refRange.Find(tempnum)
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing
    refRange(i) = tempnum
Next

End Sub
```

beware there's no limit cases checking/handling

Comment: I updated the code in my post with my current code based on your suggestion but i still got problem. I am getting error 1004: No cells were found and I am being directed to this line of code: Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, dataRng).Copy Destination:=randomSampleWs.Range("A2").Offset(rOffset). Any idea?

Comment: as I outlined, my answer has no limit cases checking/handling, which you have to take care of. that error could be thrown by one of them: you could have put in `keyArr` a keyword which is not present in the first column of your actual `dataRng` range. Or maybe the `Unique_Numbers` sub has been given inconsistent parameters (`Mx <Mn`, or `Sample > Mx - Mn + 1`). Or others (data can be nasty beasts...). Finally I point out I assumed your data in `dataRng` were "constants" (be they numbers or strings) only: should they be (also) formulas, then remove `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants`

Comment: oh. didn't see that. worked now but all rows are copied. One thing i noticed is that i got 932 rows in rawdata.xlsx but when i checked Random Sample sheet in tool.xlsm, i got 940. howcome it exceeded?

Comment: without seeing your actual data it's quite impossible to answer, you may post them. otherwise if you step through the code and see what's being done at every statement you'll get all the answers by yourself.

Comment: i attached the screenshot of how my data looks like in the question post

Comment: and how've you set `dataRng`, `keyArr` and `nRowsArr` accordingly? have you step through the code and see what's going wrong?

Comment: i'm quite new to vba so i don't really understand everything in the code. just some and i am comparing the codes from my previous works. I haven't done anything similar to what i want to accomplish now which is why i don't really have much idea on how to make it work as of now

Comment: how have you set `dataRng`, `keyArr` and `nRowsArr` in the code? see those three lines with `'<== set... ` or `'<== adapt...` comments at their left side

Comment: my whole code is in the question. i edited the dataRng so that I won't need to change the code when i got rawdata.xlsx with different amount of rows: 'Set dataRng = .Range("B2:" & .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address)'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107683/discussion-between-user3598756-and-markerbean).

Comment: you changed the code both in a inconsistent way and with no respect to your answer. Answer the following: how many columns of your raw data do you have to export (I assumed: all of them)? which dataRng (not sheet) column do you look in for "keys" and pick random sample of (I assumed: first dataRng column)? Are there other columns right of datarng ones (I assumed: no columns)? Finally, given your `set dataRng = ` statement and screenshot raw data structure `dataRng` is always the 2nd and 3rd columns of the sheet and you're looking in the former for values (AU, FJ,...) bound to be in 1st column!